# Is this property implied by a pseudorandom function?

Tags: pseudo-random-generator, pseudo-random-function

Given a keyed pseudorandom function $f: S \times X \rightarrow Y$,  where $S$ is the space of secret keys, $X$ is the input domain, and $Y$ is the range, the pseudorandom property says that given any secret key in $S$ the uniform distribution over $Y$ is indistinguishable from the distribution of $f(X)$.

Am wondering, does this property imply also the following:

*Let $f: S \times X \rightarrow Y$ be a pseudorandom function. GIven $x \in X$ and $y \in Y$, it is computationally difficult to determine the secret $s \in S$ such that $f(s,x) = y$.*

If true, does anyone know a name for this property ?

Comment: "security against key recovery", or more simply "secure".

Comment: @knaccc thank you ! ... is security against key recovery implied by pseudorandomness ? thanks

Comment: Is this homework? Think about the contrapositive of "if its outputs are indistinguishable from random then it is secure against key recovery attacks"

Comment: @Mikero, thanks ... not homework but I saw an article from doctor google which says that PRF is actually a stronger property than key recovery

Comment: I have a problem with the use of "given" in "given any secret key". To me, a given is available. I'd use "for" instead.

Comment: If you can recover the key, then it is not PRF anymore.